# R: Installing purrr from local returns error (fatal error: dplyr.h: No such file or directory)

Tags: r, installation, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

> **UPDATE** - Problem solved:
>   It seems like the way I set up `.libPaths()` (see comments below) loaded `dplyr` from a network directory, which somehow blocked the installation process of `purrr`. As soon as I installed and loaded `dplyr` from my local library I could install `purrr`.

I tried installing `purrr` from a local version of the package (`purrr_0.2.2.tar.gz`; see [CRAN website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html)). My installation attempt returns an error (**fatal error: dplyr.h: No such file or directory**):

```
> install.packages("H:/R_packages/purrr_0.2.2.tar.gz",  # directory of the downloaded file
+                  repos = NULL,
+                  type = c("source"),
+                  INSTALL_opts = "--no-test-load",
+                  lib = "H:/R_packages")               # where to install the package

'\\userhome\ABCD1234'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'purrr' ...
** package 'purrr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include     -DCOMPILING_DPLYR   -I"H:/R_packages/Rcpp/include"     -I"\\mypath//R/Lib/CRAN/3.2/dplyr/include" -I"H:/R_packages/BH/include"     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c extract.c -o extract.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include     -DCOMPILING_DPLYR   -I"H:/R_packages/Rcpp/include"     -I"\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.2/dplyr/include" -I"H:/R_packages/BH/include"     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2     -c fast-copy.cpp -o fast-copy.o
gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include     -DCOMPILING_DPLYR   -I"H:/R_packages/Rcpp/include"     -I"\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.2/dplyr/include" -I"H:/R_packages/BH/include"     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c flatten.c -o flatten.o
gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include     -DCOMPILING_DPLYR   -I"H:/R_packages/Rcpp/include"     -I"\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.2/dplyr/include" -I"H:/R_packages/BH/include"     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c map.c -o map.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include     -DCOMPILING_DPLYR   -I"H:/R_packages/Rcpp/include"     -I"\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.2/dplyr/include" -I"H:/R_packages/BH/include"     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2     -c rows-data.cpp -o rows-data.o
rows-data.cpp:2:19: fatal error: dplyr.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rows-data.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win"     -f "C:/R/R-3.2.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-3.2.1/share/make/winshlib.mk"     SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="purrr.dll"     WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="extract.o fast-copy.o flatten.o     map.o rows-data.o rows-formatter.o rows.o transpose.o utils.o vector.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'purrr'
* removing 'H:/R_packages/purrr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL --no-test-load     -l "H:\R_packages" "H:/R_packages/purrr_0.2.2.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘H:/R_packages/purrr_0.2.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit     Status
```

I used the same approach for a lot of other packages (broom, modelr, forcats etc.), and it always worked. Does anybody have an idea why the package installation fails in this particular case?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252        LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.0       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.1     DBI_0.3.1      tools_3.2.1    Rcpp_0.12.0
```

Comment: Did you install `Rcpp` package from R or using `apt-get` ?

Comment: I installed `Rcpp` the same way as I tried installing `purrr`

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()` command ?

Comment: `> .libPaths()
[1] "H:/R_packages" [2] "\\\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.2"
[3] "\\\\mypath/R/Lib/CRAN/3.1" [4] "C:/R/R-3.2.1/library"`